# Win 10 Hyper-V - use external USB disk in VM as additional storage during windows update

Tags: usb-flash-drive, windows-update, hyper-v, windows-10-v1803

I have Windows 10 Enterprise with Hyper-V enabled on my notebook and have VM with Win 10 in it. However the VM seems to not have enough storage space to perform feature update 1803. I would rather not extend the disk size as I need the VM on my notebook's drive.

During the 1803 updated installation in the VM it asked me to connect USB memory stick to use it as additional storage. I connected USB disk but it did not showed up in the drop down selection of USB disks to use (it remained empty).

I can see the USB disk in Windows Explorer - it is connected as host disk (D on MYHOSTPC). It is connected as local resource from host machine through Enhanced Session Mode. I haven't found any setting in Hyper-V how to connect it directly to guest OS. Is there a way how to add the external USB disk to guest so it could be used by the update process?

**EDIT**
I updated my question - originally I thought the update process uses Storage Spaces but from the comments I understand it does not.

Comment: Can you confirm that 0x800706BA is a failure you think it is?  The log file that is generated can confirm this for you.  I am honestly confused what, installing 1803 has to do with Storage Spaces, and not extending the system drive within with VM.

Comment: @Ramhound not sure - in system log was only the code and I googled out a bit. There is cca 14GB free of disk space. I'm not sure where to find the log, do you know the location where it should be created?

Comment: I was able to get the log using `Get-WindowsUpdateLog` method, but can't say much from it. However based on this link https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/10587/windows-10-get-help-with-upgrade-installation-errors : "0x80070070 – 0x60000 This likely indicates that your PC doesn’t have enough space available to install the upgrade. Free some space on the drive and try again."

Comment: You are going to need to extend the virtual disk if you want to install 1803.  Once you install it, you can cleanup the installation, while you can't shrink the virtual disk to it's original size you can shrink the partition from within he VM OS.  It will end up as a wash on the amount of space being used by the virtual disk on your physical disk.

Comment: OK, I can do it like this. But how about the extra disk used for storing temporary files during upgrades. I like that idea. I have other VMs and that would be much more comfortable

Comment: You are not going to be able to use Storage Spaces from within the installation environment.  If you were to add another virtual disk to the VM, then you could configure Windows to use that disk, but I don't recommend you do that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77884/discussion-between-ramhound-and-exavier).